# How to create sub-folder inside res/drawable as like in mipmap folder in android?

Tags: android, drawable

Now, I'm storing vector image of xml and raw image file inside the `res/drawable` folder. So it is easy to manage a simple and small project. When there is a case of large and heavy project than there should be managed to need sub-folder inside the drawable folder.

Example:

```
drawable
--- drawable_image
    -- logo.png
    -- backgraoung.png
--- drawable_vector
    -- button_shade.xml
    -- profile_shade.xml
```

Like the same way, we would like to have sub-folder for large application. So is there any way to manage sub-folder inside the android project?

Comment: Why don't you add your vector files in `mipmap` folders and large image files to `drawable`? 

The mipmap folders are for placing your app/launcher icons (which are shown on the homescreen) in only. Any other `drawable` assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as you are already doing.

The mipmap folders are for placing your app/launcher icons (which are shown on the homescreen) in only. Any other drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before.

Comment: The question is about creating sub-folder inside drawable folder only. Android has a facility to create folder in mipmap but in drawable.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. The app is allowed to have only one Resource but we can add folder structure to asserts.